# Monodevelop/MonoMac: No "Create Mac installer" menu item

Tags: macos, monodevelop, monomac, dmg

For [my Mono project](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/CmisSync/tree/master/SparkleShare/Mac), I want to generate a Mac package with Monodevelop/MonoMac, as described here:
http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMacPackager#Bundle_Configuration

The screenshot on the page above shows `Projects > Create Mac installer`
**PROBLEM:** I don't have this item menu.

[image]

I comply with all requirements of the page above:

- On Snow Leopard I installed XCode 3.2.6 (last XCode version that runs on Snow Leopard), the minimum requirement being XCode 3.2.5
- `Application Tools` seems to be included in XCode since 3.2.6 so I don't need to install another package.
- I installed Mono 2.10.9
- I installed Monodevelop 3.0.5
- I have MonoMac 3.0.5 enabled in Monodevelop

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation on the site is out of date.  In recent versions of MonoDevelop, these options are in your project settings under the item "Mac OS X Packaging".  The app will now be packaged along with the build process, instead of having to do the extra step each time.

The default MonoMac project templates have an "App Store" build configuration that (by default) bundles the mono framework, signs the .app, and builds a .pkg that can be distributed to the app store.